# Is asking to compare one aspect of two different works in regards to writing an acceptable question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions

The reason I ask is because both *Hitchhiker's Guide* and *Jonathan Strange* have "Lemony Snicket"/first-person-esque/characterized narrators, and I would like to know what makes them different. 
I think this belongs on Writers SE because I would like to know how to adapt or characterize various POV narration in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about literary analysis are off-topic, but if your question is "how do I write in this style?" you could ask that.  Answers will likely then offer some analysis of the style you're trying to imitate.  Your question will be stronger if you can call out some characteristics of the style that you've figured out on your own -- if you want to write in this style then, presumably, something about it appeals to you, so tell us what that is.

In other words, ask about the *writing problem* you are trying to solve.

Comment: Alright, cool. I'm struggling with comparing and contrasting the Lemony Narrators from _Jonathan Strange_ and _Hitchhiker's Guide_. You wouldn't be able to help, would you? Or know a person/place who can?

Comment: I don't know *Jonathan Strange*, sorry.  You have enough reputation to use chat, so try [chat] -- the folks in our chat room are pretty helpful!  (Traffic is erratic but generally strong through the week (tends to be empty on weekends). If there's nobody there now, go ahead and ask and you'll probably hear back from someone later.)

Comment: I'll check it out when I'm ready for the crazy. Thanks! :)

Comment: What do I do, should I start a room?

Comment: Clicking the link in my comment should take you to the site's list of rooms.  You'll see one room, called the Overlook Hotel.  Click on that and you'll be in the room.  if you haven't used chat before, you might find the short [FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq) useful.  There's no need to create a special room; this is the sort of thing our main room is *for*.